# Override delete operator

Tags: c++, oop, new-operator

I want to override delete operator in my class. Here's what I am trying to do,but not succeeding.

```
class Complex{              
    void *operator new(size_t s);
    void operator delete(void *ptr);
};

void Complex::operator delete(void *ptr){
    delete ptr;
}
```

I get the error:

> deleting void* is undefined

Comment: You probably want `::delete ptr;`

Comment: Method signatures look wrong, `new` has no `size_t` argument (only `new[]` has), but `delete` *does* have a `size_t` argument.

Comment: You can't override the `delete` operator; it's a language keyword. What you're doing is overriding `operator delete`, which is a function that gets called by the `delete` operator. That may sound like a word game, but it's an important distinction.

Comment: delete should not have size_t as argument. Because i want to write like : Complex c = new Complex();  delete c;

Comment: `operator delete` must undo whatever `operator new` did. Can you show us `operator new`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you can't `delete` a `void*`.  Try this:

```
// See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=40

#include <new> // for size_t

class Complex
{
public:
 Complex() {}
 ~Complex() {}
 static void* operator new (size_t size) {
  return new char[size];
 }
 static void operator delete (void *p) {
  return delete[] static_cast<char*>(p);
 }
};

int main () {
  Complex *p = new Complex;
  delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your declarations are correct. The problem is in the code that implements your `operator delete`: it uses the keyword `delete` instead of calling the global `operator delete`. Write it like this:

```
void Complex::operator delete(void *ptr) {
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

That's assuming that your `operator new` used the global `operator new`.

Comment: So, in the new method does it suffice to write : return (::operator new(s));

Comment: @AntonioKumar - yes, the **static member function** can be written to call the global `operator new` like that. Which, of course, raises the question of why it's there, since it just does what the compiler would do in its absence.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting through delete is quite strange, but deleting a `void*` is UB.

Also, `size_t` is not a built-in type: it is define in `<cstddef>`.

This can be fine:

```
#include <cstddef>

class Complex
{              
    void *operator new(size_t s);
    void operator delete(void *ptr);
};

void* Complex::operator new(size_t s)
{ return new char[s]; } //allocate a buffer of s bytes

void Complex::operator delete(void *ptr)
{ delete[] static_cast<char*>(ptr); } //deallocate the buffer
```

Practically, we allocate/deallocate a buffer of appropriate size coherently in new / delete.

In `new`, we ask the system to give us the bytes we need. I used `char[s]` since `char` is the unit of memory `size_t` measures: `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

In `delete` we have to give back to the system the bytes identified by `ptr`.
Since we allocated them as `char[]`, we have to delete them as `char[]`, hence the use of `delete[]` and the cast to `char*`.

Comment: So, may i know what is happening in those two lines?

Comment: Use `static_cast` here, not `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Use a `static_cast` to undo implicit conversions (`char*` implicitly converts to `void*`), `reinterpret_cast` is too strong. You aren't reinterpreting anything, just rightfully undoing an implicit cast.